# After normalize data, using regression anlaysis how to predict y?

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, normalization, linear-regression, statsmodels

I have Normalize my data and apply regression analysis to predict yield(y).
but my predicted output also gives in normalized (in 0 to 1)
I want my predicted answer in my correct data numbers,not in 0 to 1.

Data:

```
Total_yield(y)    Rain(x)  
      64799.30   720.1  
      77232.40   382.9  
      88487.70  1198.2  
      77338.20   341.4  
      145602.05   406.4 
      67680.50   325.8 
      84536.20   791.8 
      99854.00   748.6 
      65939.90  1552.6 
      61622.80  1357.7
      66439.60   344.3
```

Next,I have normalize data using this  code :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
import pandas
import numpy
dataframe = pandas.read_csv('/home/desktop/yield.csv')
array = dataframe.values
X = array[:,0:2]
scaler = Normalizer().fit(X)
normalizedX = scaler.transform(X)
print(normalizedX)

     Total_yield      Rain
0       0.999904  0.013858
1       0.999782  0.020872
2       0.999960  0.008924
3       0.999967  0.008092
4       0.999966  0.008199
5       0.999972  0.007481
6       0.999915  0.013026
7       0.999942  0.010758
8       0.999946  0.010414
9       0.999984  0.005627
10      0.999967  0.008167
```

Next, I use this normalize value to calculate R-sqaure using following code :

```
array=normalizedX
data = pandas.DataFrame(array,columns=['Total_yield','Rain'])
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
lm = smf.ols(formula='Total_yield ~ Rain', data=data).fit()
lm.summary()
```

Output :

```
<class 'statsmodels.iolib.summary.Summary'>
"""
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:            Total_yield   R-squared:                       0.752
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.752
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     1066.
Date:                Thu, 09 Feb 2017   Prob (F-statistic):          2.16e-108
Time:                        14:21:21   Log-Likelihood:                 941.53
No. Observations:                 353   AIC:                            -1879.
Df Residuals:                     351   BIC:                            -1871.
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept      1.0116      0.001    948.719      0.000         1.009     1.014
Rain          -0.3013      0.009    -32.647      0.000        -0.319    -0.283
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                      408.798   Durbin-Watson:                   1.741
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):            40636.533
Skew:                          -4.955   Prob(JB):                         0.00
Kurtosis:                      54.620   Cond. No.                         10.3
==============================================================================
```

Now, R-square = 0.75 ,

```
regression model : y =  b0 + b1  *x

Yield  =  b0 + b1 * Rain

Yield  =  intercept + coefficient for Rain * Rain

Now when I use my data value for Rain data then it will gives this answer :
Yield  =  1.0116    + ( -0.3013 * 720.1(mm)) = -215.95

-215.95yield is wrong, 

 And when I use normalize value for rain data then predicted yield comes in normalize value in between 0 to 1.

 I want predict if rainfall will be 720.1 mm then how many yield will be there? 

If anyone help me how to get predicted yield ? I want to compare  Predicted yield vs given yield.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you should not use Normalizer in this case. It doesn't normalize across features. It does it along rows. You may not want it.

Use [MinMaxScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) or [RobustScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.RobustScaler.html) to scale each feature. See the [preprocessing docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html) for more details.

Second, these classes have a `inverse_transform()` function which can convert the predicted y value back to original units.

```
x = np.asarray([720.1,382.9,1198.2,341.4,406.4,325.8,
                791.8,748.6,1552.6,1357.7,344.3]).reshape(-1,1)
y = np.asarray([64799.30,77232.40,88487.70,77338.20,145602.05,67680.50,
              84536.20,99854.00,65939.90,61622.80,66439.60]).reshape(-1,1)

scalerx = RobustScaler()
x_scaled = scalerx.fit_transform(x)

scalery = RobustScaler()    
y_scaled = scalery.fit_transform(y)
```

Call your `statsmodel.OLS` on these scaled data. 
While predicting, first transform your test data:

```
x_scaled_test = scalerx.transform([720.1])
```

Apply your regression model on this value and get the result. This result of y will be according to the scaled data.

```
Yield_scaled  =  b0 + b1 * x_scaled_test
```

So inverse transform it to get data in original units.

```
Yield_original = scalery.inverse_transform(Yield_scaled)
```

But in my opinion, this linear model will not give much accuracy, because when I plotted your data, this is the result.[image: Rain(x) Yield(y) plot]

This data will not be fitted with linear models. Use other techniques, or get more data.

Comment: When I use MinMax scaler & standardize then I will get R-square : 0.07 ,  And when I have use then I will get R-square : 0.75 , that why I choose, normalize, okay i will use RobustScaler ,

Comment: I am not understand this meaning "  inverse_transform() function which can convert the predicted y value back to original units ". can you explain me please it will helps for me

Comment: It means that it will invert the scaling, and get the original value back from the scaled value

Comment: I have using RobustScaler, but i am confuse in after I get slope and intercept value, can i use same value for original data value ? I mean if I have get   slope = 0.58  and intercept = 0.89  using robust scaler then I have to use same for predict yield ?

Comment: You `transform` your test data according to the same scaler you used during training, then predict and then `inverse_transform` the result back to get answer in original units. I will add code to show.

Comment: It will very helpful ,if you give code for that.Thanks

Comment: If you are satisfied, close the question and / or accepting the answer. If you want more help, either edit the question or post a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: when I use  x_scaled_test = scalerx.transform([720.1]) this gives same number x_scaled for 720.1 , and for b0 and b1 I have use same method what I have use in my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135278/discussion-between-vivek-kumar-and-kiran-prajapati).